# npm jqwidgets-framework install & license

Tags: npm, jqwidget, jqxwidgets

I have license of jqWidgets with some other account & earlier I have added required js & styles files by including downloaded folder in solution. It was working fine then.

Now I wish to install jqwidgets-framework via npm but now I am getting watermark in all grids & controls, which is shown when we are using jqWidgets without license.

How to apply/get license for npm packages within .NET solution using both HTML & react controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted same question on jqwidgets community forum:
http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/npm-jqwidgets-framework-install-license/

Got this Answer:

> Licensed version is available from our website only. It is not
>   available through npm.We do not distribute freely our intellectual
>   property through NPM.
>
> Peter Stoev
>
> jQWidgets Team
>   http://www.jqwidgets.com

So you need to download licensed file from jqwidgets.com & then need to add them as static js resource in your application & repeat this whenever you need any update or new version.